# Change default password on ActiveMQ Web console (ServiceMix version)

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-karaf, jaas, apache-servicemix

I 've changed the `JAAS karaf` default password in `/etc/users.properties` for security reason.

The  modification works when I access to `Karaf` Web Console (`8181/system/console/bundles`) but not in `ActiveMQ Web Console` (`8181/activemqweb/index.jsp`) which keep `karaf:karaf` credentials).

I don't find any other configuration file for `ActiveMQ` web console.

My `jetty.xml` file uses `JAASLoginService` with karaf realm (default configuration).

*Tools versions :*

- ServiceMix 6.1.2
- Karaf 3.0.7
- ActiveMQ 5.12.3

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change connectionFactory bean in your `webapps/admin/WEB-INF/webconsole-embeded.xml` to something like this:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost"/>
    <property name="userName" value="system"/>
    <property name="password" value="manager"/>
</bean>
```

Please Refer to **Web Console** section of [ActiveMQ Security Page](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html).

---

You can also take a look at [Web Console Page](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html) if you wish to change credentials of the whole Web Console Server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My issue is about HTTP authentication not JMS. The configuration on the ActiveMQ Web console page is not  usuable in OSGI integration.